# Selenium Chromedriver can't print version without also being headless

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using C# and Selenium and Chromedriver to run tests.

I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
```

But it only crashes if I remove the `_chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");`, and only on a Mac. I tested on an Intel Mac, an M1 Mac, and a Windows. Windows runs without headed just fine.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

ChromeOptions _chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

_chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
_chromeOptions.AddArgument("version");

IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeOptions);

Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
Driver.Close();
```

From existing SO posts and other resources I found, I have tried adding various other arguments to chromeoptions including:
`--headless=false`
`--no-sandbox`
`--disable-gpu`
`--verbose`

and also specifying the binary:

```
_chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome";
```

I'm using an M1 Macbook Pro, Visual Studio for Mac 17.4.3 (build 21), Selenium.Webdriver 4.8.0, Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.7400, and Google Chrome 109.0.5414.87 (Official Build) (arm64)

Because the driver is initialized deep in an in-house library, I can't simply remove the `version` line, and I need it to not be headless so I can verify the test I'm writing actually does what it's supposed to.